# cannot import a node_module using require?

Tags: javascript

I am importing a module like this in commonjs:

```
var ApiAi = require('api-ai-javascript').ApiAiClient
```

But I can't use it like this:

```
var client = new ApiAiClient({ accessToken: '459833646b974d85a1d853c7hdg' });
```

I get an error:

> export * from "./es6/ApiAiClient";
>
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) keyword. It will look something like this `import ApiAi from 'api-api'` and then maybe the export keyword will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run npm install of the module you are trying to use? You can check this if you have a node_modules folder, the folder 'api-ai-javascript' should be around.

Are you using an updated node version? Maybe you are using an old version of node and this package you are trying to use requires a newer one (check with `node -v` within a terminal).

Another thing, this line:

`var ApiAi = require('api-ai-javascript').ApiAiClient`

Means you are importing the ApiAiClient from the module 'api-ai-javascript', and you are keeping a reference to it within the variable '**ApiAi**'. So, if you want to use it, you need to call:

`var client = new ApiAi({ accessToken: '459833646b974d85a1d853c7hdg' });`

Notice I changed `new ApiAiClient` to `new ApiAi`.